# Camera error cannot connect to the camera

Tags: android, android-camera

i am working on `camera` `activity` for capturing `image`,while calling camera activity it displaying `Camera` error cannot connect to the `camera` please can anyone give explanation about this error

i am calling this one

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_IMAGE);
```

error message:

```
camera error
cannot connect to the camera
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add permission in your manifest file

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

**If still not working then Edit AVD and go to Back Camera selected Emulated**

Comment: thanks for ur reply,i already given permissions and i tested in devices it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Also you check Like

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
      // your Intent Goes Here Like
        Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
    } else {   
        UtilityCommon.showDialogwithTitle(context,context.getResources().getString(R.string.strvalidcamera));               

    }
```

Also Add Require Permision in Your `AndroidMAnifest.xml` file